# ILoggerProvider Dispose function not invoked

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

The ILoggerProvider Dispose function is not being invoked when I am running a unit test. Here is how I am initating the logger provider:

```
.AddTransient<ILogger, MyLogger>()

.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
{       
    loggingBuilder.ClearProviders();  
    loggingBuilder.AddProvider(new LoggerProvider(config));
})
```

and in InitializeTest() I am getting the logger like this

```
 logger = servicesProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
```

the loggerprovider class:

```
public class LoggerProvider : ILoggerProvider
    {
        public IConfiguration Config { get; }
        private MyLogger logger;
        public LoggerProvider(IConfiguration config)
        {
            Config = config;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Create logger method. 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="categoryName">Category name</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public ILogger CreateLogger(string categoryName)
        {
            logger = new MyLogger(Config);
            return logger;
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Dispose.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            logger.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Unit test part

```
[TestInitialize()]
public void InitializeTest()
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory
            .GetCurrentDirectory()) Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
        .Build();
    servicesProvider = ServiceProvider.BuildDi(config);
    logger = servicesProvider.GetRequiredService<ILogger>();
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestInformation()
{
    try
    {
        logger.LogInformation("Testing");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Assert.Fail(ex.Message);
    }

    Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
```

Is dispose not triggered after running a unit test?

Comment: How does your `LoggerProvider` and test look like?

Comment: Hi @PavelAnikhouski please see the updated code

Comment: If you need `Dispose` to be called after method `TestInformation` is finished, then initialize service provider inside of `TestInformation` and don't forget to to define `using` scope. So something like this: `using var servicesProvider = ServiceProvider.BuildDi(config);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking for the resources inside the `ServiceProvider` to be disposed, the `ServiceProvider` needs to be disposed itself (unless the resource is scoped, then the scope needs to be disposed).

So in this case `ServiceProvider` needs to be moved to within the test and it needs to be wrapped inside a `using`:

```cs
using (var servicesProvider = ServiceProvider.BuildDi(config))
{
    ...
}
```

Or the new way:

```cs
using var servicesProvider = ServiceProvider.BuildDi(config);
```

Here is a [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yyk5EA) illustrating this behavior.